# Can a Managed Metadata Column in a Document Library have Place Holder text

Tags: document-library, term-set, managed-metadata-column

I've mapped a Managed Metadata Column to a TermSet in the Term Store.  There is a concern that users won't think to click on the tag icon that brings up the Term Store values.  Is it possible to have Place Holder text in the field that tells the user to click the icon?

Answer (score 0):

I think OOTB it is not possible to have place holder text inside the managed metadata field itself.

**Workaround**:

1. While creating new managed metadata in document library, you can add the description of this field. This description will be shown down below the managed metadata field on forms.

See image below for reference:

[image]